# Pass custom data via Paypal Standards Payment Button created via Paypal Admin

Tags: paypal, transactions

I want to utilize paypal's button creator on the paypal admin to create paypal payment standards button. However I want to pass a custom/dynamic data to the form as well.

ex. I have a registration form where users can fill up the form and click pay now to finish registration. I want to pass along with it a registration form number or registration id (either I'm gonna pass it via one of paypal's pass through fields, custom, item_number or invoice) so that if the payment is successful, paypal will send me a notification via ipn, my ipn listener then process the message, check on the ipn message the registration form number, then activate the registration on the db.

I can accomplish that via coding my custom paypal standards payment button manually, but, I want to take advantage of hosting a button via paypal for security.

how will I able to accomplish this if I where to use a hosted button on paypal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it, you can use these following fields to accomplish the above task.

```
custom

invoice
```

create a paypal hosted button via paypal admin, paste the html generated code on your page, then you can alter it to include the following fields.

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="55555">

<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="88888">
```

I tried it via sandbox and it worked.

However you cannot use item_number field, if you add an item_number field on the html generated code by paypal, it will still fulfill the transaction, but it wont send any ipn message to your ipn listener. weird. (I tried it via sandbox)